# How to debug Rocket Chat error during oauth with custom service?

Tags: http, meteor, oauth

I am setting up a custom oauth server with Rocket Chat (Meteor). Almost everything is okay, however Rocket Chat fails when trying to query the `/oauth/token` endpoint to log the user in.

The endpoint is not touched, so I guess the requests is not even sent. The 
[error is thrown here](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/master/packages/rocketchat-custom-oauth/server/custom_oauth_server.js#L116) and the message is `Parse Error`.

I've tried to read the `meteor/http` code, but I did not manage to figure which package could be responsible to this `Parse Error`.

I can't figure the right way to get more info. Edit: I've tried to install Rocket Chat locally and could not reproduce. This error only happens on a live instance.

Any idea what could cause this issue or what step I could take to debug this?

Comment: If this happens only in production it is helpful to add how you deployed the app, since custom Meteor deployment has many pitfalls and traps ready for you to jump in.

Comment: I think I've figured this out: my mistake is that my app is in production (on Azure), but my oauth server is localhost since I am developping it. So the app in production obviously can't reach out localhost, though the Error message is obscure. I'll do more test and post an answer when I am 100% sure. The solution would be to have either both apps on local or both apps in production.

Answer (score 1):

This error "Parse Error" can appear when the URL is not correct but still a valid URL. The endpoint will return HTML instead of a valid JSON and thus produce this error.

Example: you host your Rocket Chat on "my-chat.com", and use "localhost:3000/oauth", on your own development machine, as your oauth server.

This will fail, because Rocket Chat will query "localhost:3000", but from the Rocket Chat standpoint localhost is the server it is hosted on, not your own machine. So the request will hit Rocket Chat itself instead of your local development server and produce this error.